# Keyboard doesn't appears every focus

Tags: reactjs, react-native, autofocus, react-native-paper

I'm using the `<InputText>` of `react-native-paper` for my app.
And i'm using the `autofocus` property everytime I switch from a view to another, so i can type directly when I arrive on the screen.

But the problem is the keyboard appears randomly ... Sometimes the keyboard comes alone and sometimes I have to tap in the input to reveal the keyboard...

This is an example of the Input I use everywhere :

```
<TextInput
                    label="Article"
                    value={this.state.article}
                    onChangeText={article => this.setState({article})}
                    onSubmitEditing={this.submitStepSaisie1}
                    autoFocus
                    style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
                />
```

I tried using ref like this, in my constructor :

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props);
    this.fieldOne = React.createRef();
    this.fieldTwo = React.createRef();
}
```

And on my TextInput :

```
<TextInput ref={this.fieldOne} />
```

But when I call the `this.fieldOne.current.focus()` it returnes me the following error : `Cannot read property 'focus' of null.`

Do you guys have a trick ?
Thanks !

Comment: you can use ref of that element and call focus after component mount

Comment: I tried, but it seems in react native ref doesn't works anymore ? Always called some errors when i tried to achieve it... Or maybe ref doesn't works good on react native paper element

Comment: what error exactly??

Comment: I just edited my question

Comment: pass ref in your `<input />`

Comment: Do you have an example ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { TextInput as NativeTextInput } from 'react-native';

<TextInput
  label="Article"
  value={this.state.article}
  onChangeText={article => this.setState({article})}
  onSubmitEditing={this.submitStepSaisie1}
  autoFocus
  style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent'}}
  render={(props) => <NativeTextInput {...props} ref={this.fieldOne}>}
/>
```

I dont have the time to test this but this might work.

Comment: I finally added a timeout before the focus function... The only way it works.